# Haskell: if-then-else blocks and data with asymmetrical constructors

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, purely-functional

I have the following data which can have a Ship or not:

```
data LaserCollisionResult = NoCollision | LaserToLaserCollision Ship | LaserToShipCollision Ship deriving (Eq, Show)
```

then, later on, I am trying to check if a LaserCollisionResult is of type LaserToLaserCollision, but I get an error. My [lambda] function is this:

```
laserPaths' = map (\(p,r) -> if r == LaserToLaserCollision then doSomethingWith p else p) $ zip laserPaths laserCollisionResults
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Couldn't match type 'LaserCollisionResult' with 'Ship -> LaserCollisionResult'
Expected type: [Ship -> LaserCollisionResult]
Actual type: [LaserCollisionResult]
In the second argument of 'zip', namely laserCollisionResults.
```

How can I check whether a LaserCollisionResult in laserCollisionResults is of type LaserToLaserCollision?

Comment: `map f $ zip xs ys` is the same as `zipWith (curry f) xs ys`. You can simplify `laserPaths'` to `zipWith (\p r -> case r of {...}) laserPaths laserCollisionResults`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match on `r` e.g.

```
laserPaths' = map (\(p,r) -> if isLaserCollision r then doSomethingWith p else p) $ zip laserPaths laserCollisionResults
  where isLaserCollision (LaserToLaserCollision _) = True
        isLaserCollision _ = False
```

or you can match inline:

```
 laserPaths' = map (\(p, r) -> case r of { (LaserToLaserCollision _) -> doSomethingWith p ; _ -> p}) $ zip laserPaths laserCollisionResults
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace your lambda by

```
(\(p,r) -> case r of {LaserToLaserCollision _ -> doSomethingWith p; _ -> p})
```

By the way, for this you don't need to derive an `Eq` instance.